# Extending reactjs Apps on previous apps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am developing a reactjs application with webpack but i want to know if i can create expantion app to extend the features of my current app.Like wordpress.Suppose my current app have no email verification nd sms verification.But i want to make an add on to add this feture in the pro version.

If i can do like in wordpress

`do_action('add_new_feature', 'function-to-do-the-features')`

Also can this be done with custom react hooks? As we can create a custom hooks in react

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these features (like your SMS verification) are built ahead of time and are allowed for some users who are enrolled in these features or have activated these features in their account.

These features are activated from the database level (such as setting the SMS verification column to true for a user) after that the user will be able to see and manage his email verifications.

this kind of work is basically done on the backend side.

Once the feature is enabled you can show SMS verification for that your user in their dashboard to access and manage the sms verification feature.

There is no mandatory requirement of using hooks for this scenario.